# Laptop air vent closed with piece of plastic from inside

Tags: laptop, fan

I have a new laptop with an air vent with what looks to be a piece of plastic or tape that is stuck against it on the inside.

Is this a manufacturing mistake? Should it safe to remove by either opening laptop and removing it or piercing it with something sharp? Or is this deliberate from the manufacturers? Can it be that this somehow improves airflow to other parts of the laptop?

I have a Lenovo G50 and couldn't find anything about this regarding that model.

[image]

Note the left side one can see a grill under the vent. The right side is smooth shiny black plastic underneath. It is quite hard.

Comment: Please post a *clear* picture.

Comment: @i_am_root Added an imgur link. On mobile so cannot upload. It is still kind of hard to see

Comment: You can use a hardware monitor to check the internal temperatures and run a game or test software to check how hot things get under load.

Comment: I accidentally undid Julians edit. Cant seem to fix on mobile :-(

Comment: @JulianKnight good idea. The fans don't seem noisy when playing games etc. But Ill check the temp when I get the chance.

Comment: *"I have a new laptop" -- Since it's new, then contact the manufacturer for an expert answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this diagram from the [Hardware Maintenance Manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g_z_50_series_hmm.pdf) for this product, this looks correct.

[image: Lenovo G50 Thermal Door]

But, as it's a Lenovo, feel free to follow the HMM and pull the back cover off and take a look for yourself.

Comment: As you said in your comment to Jarmand, Michael, it's probably there to prevent poking the hard-drive. I'll check it out myself later. Thanks! This reassures me that it was deliberate.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that when it comes to laptop cooling, airflow is the key, not just volume. I have seen some PCs cool better if there is a duct-like system that the fan can pump air through, as opposed to just having it wide open.

It is also important to note that if it was a blunder, it would've been one that was easily seen during assembly. If not, at least QC should have caught it.

The above points make me believe that it is **probably** intentional, even though it's an ugly fix to whatever problem they were trying to fix. I suggest monitor temperatures for a bit. If fans struggle a lot, or the temperatures are abnormally high, try removing it to see if it improves the situation.

Comment: After looking at the HMM, it looks like the HDD is under that plastic cover. They probably don't want people poking it.